# Im suppose to do black and white strips in python with tkdraw

Tags: tkinter

So, im pretty sure the problem comes from my loop but i can't figure why it's not working properly... Big chance i just did a noob mistake but i don't get it

```
import tkdraw.basic as graph
graph.open_win(120, 160)

def segment_horiz(y, x1, x2):
    for i in range(x1, x2):
        graph.plot(y, i)


def rectangle(y1, y2, x1, x2):
    for i in range(y1, y2):
        segment_horiz(i, x1, x2)

def rayure_vertic(haut, larg, larg_bande):
    for x in range(0, larg, larg_bande):
        rectangle(x, haut, larg_bande, larg_bande*2)

rayure_vertic(120,160,20)
"rectangle(20,60,40,60)"
graph.wait()
```

here's the full code, [and here is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/By7De.png).

i wish everyone coming here a nice day ! and good luck on your coding stuff :D

Comment: The arguments of `rectangle()` are `(y1, y2, x1, x2)`, but why do you call it using `(x, haut, larg_bande, larg_bande*2)`? I think it should be `for x in range(0, larg, larg_bande*2): rectangle(0, haut, x, x+larg_bande)` instead.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.